# I get an error while invoking C# code via PowerShell 5.1

Tags: c#, powershell, focus, pinvoke

There's a code for checking the Focus Assist status on [GitHub](https://github.com/DCourtel/Windows_10_Focus_Assist/blob/master/FocusAssistLibrary/FocusAssistLib.cs)

The code works perfectly and is compilable. But unfortunately it doesn't work using P/Invoke in PowerShell 5.1 at all (on PowerShell 7.3 does):

> Invalid expression term 'uint'

And many more errors

My attempt to make it work

```
$Focus = @{
    Namespace        = "WinAPI"
    Name             = "Focus"
    Language         = "CSharp"
    MemberDefinition = @"
[DllImport("NtDll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern uint NtQueryWnfStateData(IntPtr pStateName, IntPtr pTypeId, IntPtr pExplicitScope, out uint nChangeStamp, out IntPtr pBuffer, ref uint nBufferSize);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WNF_TYPE_ID
{
    public Guid TypeId;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct WNF_STATE_NAME
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
    public uint[] Data;

    public WNF_STATE_NAME(uint Data1, uint Data2) : this()
    {
        uint[] newData = new uint[2];
        newData[0] = Data1;
        newData[1] = Data2;
        Data = newData;
    }
}

public enum FocusAssistState
{
    NOT_SUPPORTED = -2,
    FAILED = -1,
    OFF = 0,
    PRIORITY_ONLY = 1,
    ALARMS_ONLY = 2
};

// Returns the state of Focus Assist if available on this computer
public static FocusAssistState GetFocusAssistState()
{
    try
    {
        WNF_STATE_NAME WNF_SHEL_QUIETHOURS_ACTIVE_PROFILE_CHANGED = new WNF_STATE_NAME(0xA3BF1C75, 0xD83063E);
        uint nBufferSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr));
        IntPtr pStateName = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WNF_STATE_NAME)));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(WNF_SHEL_QUIETHOURS_ACTIVE_PROFILE_CHANGED, pStateName, false);
        bool success = NtQueryWnfStateData(pStateName, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, out uint nChangeStamp, out IntPtr pBuffer, ref nBufferSize) == 0;
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pStateName);
        if (success)
        {
            return (FocusAssistState)pBuffer;
        }
    }
    catch { }

    return FocusAssistState.FAILED;
}
"@
}

if (-not ("WinAPI.Focus" -as [type]))
{
    Add-Type @Focus
}
[WinAPI.Focus]::GetFocusAssistState()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Add-Type` in Windows PowerShell uses a version of the C# compiler that only compiles C# 4.0 (or 5.0, can't remember).

Therefore, the inline declarations in this method call:

```
bool success = NtQueryWnfStateData(pStateName, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, out uint nChangeStamp, out IntPtr pBuffer, ref nBufferSize) == 0;
```

Are not recognized as valid C# syntax.

Change the statement to use already-declared locals to make it work:

```
uint nChangeStamp = 0;
IntPtr pBuffer = IntPtr.Zero;

bool success = NtQueryWnfStateData(pStateName, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, out nChangeStamp, out pBuffer, ref nBufferSize) == 0;
```

Comment: Perfect! Hope it will work after next Windows update)

Comment: @farag That'd be cool, but I wouldn't count on it - major features of Windows PowerShell 5.1 are basically frozen, there's no active development beyond security updates :)